# How to Split a CSV file by line and then by semicolons

Tags: java, csv, split, filereader

Hi all I have a CSV file like this:

```
 ban;frst_name;last_nam;adrs_provnc;accnt_type_id....
 ban1;frst_name1;last_nam1;adrs_provnc1;accnt_type_id....
 ....
```

I want to put this file into a datatype in which I can access each line as well as each field of everyline. Example: if I want the second line of the file then I should have --

```
"ban1;frst_name1;last_nam1;adrs_provnc1;accnt_type_id...."
```

And if I want the second field of second line I should have:

```
"frst_name1"
```

Is there a way I can do this , by which I can get access to both lines and fields.

This is what i coded

```
 public class cvsreader {    
List<List<String>> cust_data = new ArrayList<List<String>>(); // declared a list of list   
public void run() throws IOException {

    String cust_line = "";

    String delimeter = ";";

    String cust_inputfile = "C:/input.csv"; // input file


    BufferedReader cust_br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cust_inputfile));

    while ((cust_line = cust_br.readLine()) != null){

        cust_data = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(cust_line.split(delimeter))); // stored data from cust_line(string) to cust_data (list of list, so did type casting from list to array)
        System.out.println(cust_data);

        }

    }
}
```

it gives me output like below

```
[[ban,frst_name,last_nam,adrs_provnc,accnt_type_id....]]
[[ban1,frst_name1,last_nam1,adrs_provnc1,accnt_type_id....]]    
[[....                                                    ]]
```

now if i print

```
System.out.println(cust_data.get(0));
```

it gives output like this-

```
[ban,frst_name,last_nam,adrs_provnc,accnt_type_id....]    
[ban1,frst_name1,last_nam1,adrs_provnc1,accnt_type_id....]    
[....                                                    ]
```

the one sqaure braces has been reduced but instead it should have given only the frst line.

```
[ban,frst_name,last_nam,adrs_provnc,accnt_type_id....]
```

and now if i print

```
System.out.println(cust_data.get(0).get(0));
```

it prints the below

```
ban    
ban1
```

without square braces but instead it should have printed only the first field of first line that is-
ban.

please if anyone can now understand what actually has to be done to get desired result please suggest.

Comment: Let's see some code.

Comment: i dont have any code , i want to know how to do this

Comment: It seems like each row represents a User, or an Account, or something like that. So you just need a List<User>. To access the first name of the third user, you would use `list.get(2).getFirstName()`. Google for "Java CSV parser" to find a library able to parse CSV, and use it to parse the file and transform each line to a User.

Comment: search for `java parse csv`

Comment: @Anant, generally you get better results here by showing what you tried. It isn't always clear from a description what the constraints and requirements are, and SO isn't here to do your homework for you. Anyway, the answer with the links in it is your new starting point.

Answer (score 0):

This answer for reading line by line:
[How to read a large text file line by line using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java)

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       // process the line.
    }
}
```

This answer for splitting a string: [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

```
String string = "004-034556";
String[] parts = string.split("-");
String part1 = parts[0]; // 004
String part2 = parts[1]; // 034556
```

This page for complete example of parsing CSV: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

All code copy pasted from other SO threads.

Comment: Don't just post URLs as the answer, include relevant information from the URLs in your answer in case the the URL changes or is no longer valid.

Comment: Sorry, was thinking since it was to SO pages the url would probably not change, and point to the relevant discussion instead of me taking it out of context.

Comment: thanks everyone, will search for CSV parser and let you know where i reach with that.

Comment: @JensB-The URL which you gave has an example of reading a a csv file spliting it by semicolan and printing its data. i want to split my file line by line and then field by filed.